# Using discrete elements to optimize the design of another element - Expanding on Circuit Example

Tags: openmdao

I've read through most of the questions posted on here tagged with OpenMDAO on discrete variables and have reviewed the following documentation [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_components/discrete_variables.html) but I cannot find an answer to my question.

Here is a description of my use-case:

Lets start with the circuit example [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/examples/circuit_analysis_examples.html). Now lets assume that I have a set of R values I would like to use. Perhaps in my box of hardware I have 3 types of resistors available to me that I must take advantage of.

With the resistors available, I would like to find a configuration that constrains the net current to 0 but minimizes the voltages at the nodes. Is OpenMDAO capable of taking in sets of discrete variables to select an optimal design for the other components? What would be the proper methods for this use-case? Is there any documentation or publication that I could use as a reference for this type of effort?

Overall I'm looking to use OpenMDAO to define bespoke hardware requirements in cooperation with available COTS components to meet a performance need. Am I barking up the right tree?

Answer (score 0):

There is some work on discrete optimization in OpenMDAO. There is specifically some support for [discrete variables](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.19.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/discrete_variables.html?highlight=discrete) in components. The [SimpleGADriver](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.19.0/features/building_blocks/drivers/genetic_algorithm.html) also supports discrete variables. If you are looking for something more advanced than that, you can check out the [AMIEGO](https://github.com/Kenneth-T-Moore/AMIEGO) driver.

Im not fully sure how to pose the optimization problem you've described, but there is some relevant OpenMDAO code for circuit analysis in the [Zappy](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/zappy) library that you might wan to check out.